# How to properly import the libphonelib to the java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, libphonenumber

I'm trying to use the `PhoneNumberMatcher` from the libphonenumber library. After adding the jar file to my project and setting the BuildPath, I was able to import classes to my project:

`import com.google.i18n.phonenumbers.*;`

Inside the lib, there is a class named `PhoneNumberMatcher.class`. I've been trying to reach it but this class name isn't included in suggestions I normally get when I press **Ctrl + Space.**

If I insist and write the name class, eclipse will underline the name and the message **"The type PhoneNumberMatcher is not visible".** 
Newly I realized that the class has a small blue flag icon is in the project explorer.

It's not the only one that has such a blue flag, then I try the other classes and I realized that all classes with this blue flag isn't accessible. That's why I think these classes probably are private, or for internal use of the lib.

I'm trying to create a tool to extract phone numbers out of a text and I read this lib is exactly for it.

How do I use the `PhonNumberMatcher` class in my java project, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 CharSequence text = "Call me at +1 425 882-8080 for details.";
 String country = "US";
 PhoneNumberUtil util = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();

 // Find the first phone number match:
 PhoneNumberMatch m = util.findNumbers(text, country).iterator().next();

 // rawString() contains the phone number as it appears in the text.
 "+1 425 882-8080".equals(m.rawString());

 // start() and end() define the range of the matched subsequence.
 CharSequence subsequence = text.subSequence(m.start(), m.end());
 "+1 425 882-8080".contentEquals(subsequence);

 // number() returns the the same result as PhoneNumberUtil.parse()
 // invoked on rawString().
 util.parse(m.rawString(), country).equals(m.number());
```

https://javadoc.io/doc/com.googlecode.libphonenumber/libphonenumber

Comment: This does not answer the "The type PhoneNumberMatcher is not visible" part of the question

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer Chana.
I did actually was able to use the library, but then I realized that the lib was to complicated to use for me, so I did write my own code to extract German phone numbers, IBANs, Postcodes and money amounts and then classify then:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class NumberExtractorAndClassifier {

public static final String REGEXPhoneNumbers = "(0|0049\\s?|\\+49\\s?|\\(\\+49\\)\\s?|\\(0\\)\\s?){1}([0-9]{2,4})([ \\-\\/]?[0-9]{1,10})+";
public static final String REGEXIbanNumbers = "([A-Z][ -]?){2}([0-9]([ -]?)*){12,30}";
public static final String REGEXAmounts = "(\\d+([.,]?)\\d{0,}([.,]?)\\d*(\\s*)(\\$|â‚¬|EUR|USD|Euro|Dollar))|((\\$|€|EUR|USD|Euro|Dollar)(\\s*)\\d+([.,]?\\d{0,}([.,]?)\\d*))";
public static final String REGEXPostCode = "\\b((?:0[1-46-9]\\d{3})|(?:[1-357-9]\\d{4})|(?:[4][0-24-9]\\d{3})|(?:[6][013-9]\\d{3}))\\b";
public static String TextToAnalyze;
public static String CopyOfText = "";
public static int ExaminatedIndex = 0;
public static List<String> ExtractedPhoneNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> ExtractedIbanNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> ExtractedAmounts = new ArrayList<String>();
public static List<String> ExtractedPostCodes = new ArrayList<String>();
public static final String EMPTY_STRING = "";


/**
 * @brief Constructor: initializes the needed variables and call the different methods in order to find an classify the Numbers
 * 
 * @param Text: is the input text that need to be analyzed 
 */
public NumberExtractorAndClassifier(String Text) {
    
    TextToAnalyze = Text;    //- This variable is going to have our complete text
    CopyOfText = Text;       //- This variable is going to have the missing text to analyze
    
    //- We extract the amounts first in order to do not confuse them later with a phone number, IBAN or post-code
    ExtractedAmounts = ExtractAmounts();  
    for (String Amount : ExtractedAmounts)
    {
        //- We cut them out of the text in order to do not confuse them later with a IBAN, phone number or post-code
        String safeToUseInReplaceAllString = Pattern.quote(Amount);
        CopyOfText = CopyOfText.replaceAll(safeToUseInReplaceAllString, "");
        System.out.println("Found amount -------> " + Amount);
    }
    
    //- We extract the IBAN secondly in order to do not confuse them later with a phone number or post-code
    ExtractedIbanNumbers = ExtracIbanNumbers();
    for (String Iban : ExtractedIbanNumbers)
    {
        //- We cut them out of the text in order to do not confuse them later with a phone number, or post-code
        String safeToUseInReplaceAllString = Pattern.quote(Iban);
        CopyOfText = CopyOfText.replaceAll(safeToUseInReplaceAllString, "");
        System.out.println("Found IBAN ---------> " + Iban);
    }
            
    //- We extract the phone numbers thirdly in order to do not confuse them later with a post-code
    ExtractedPhoneNumbers = ExtractPhoneNumbers();
    for( String number : ExtractedPhoneNumbers )
    {
        //- We cut them out of the text in order to do not confuse them later with a post-code
        String safeToUseInReplaceAllString = Pattern.quote(number);
        CopyOfText = CopyOfText.replaceAll(safeToUseInReplaceAllString, "");
        System.out.println("Found number -------> " + number);
    }
    
    ExtractedPostCodes = ExtractPostCodes();
    for( String PostCode : ExtractedPostCodes)
    {
        System.out.println("Found post code ----> " + PostCode);
    }

}




/**
 * @Brief Method extracts phone numbers out of the text with help of REGEXPhoneNumbers
 * 
 * @return List of strings with all the found numbers.
 */
public static List<String> ExtractPhoneNumbers(){
    //Initializing our variables
    List<String> FoundNumbers =  new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean LineContainsNumber = true;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEXPhoneNumbers);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(CopyOfText);
    while (LineContainsNumber) {
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String NumberFoundByTheMatcher = matcher.group(0);
            FoundNumbers.add(NumberFoundByTheMatcher);
        }
        else{LineContainsNumber = false;}
    }
    return FoundNumbers;
}



/**
 * @Brief Method extracts IBAN numbers out of the text with help of REGEXIbanNumbers
 * 
 * @return List of strings with all the found IBANS numbers.
 */
public static List<String> ExtracIbanNumbers(){
    //Initializing our variables
    List<String> FoundIbans =  new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean LineContainsIban = true;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEXIbanNumbers);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(CopyOfText);
    while (LineContainsIban) {
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String NumberFoundByTheMatcher = matcher.group(0);
            FoundIbans.add(NumberFoundByTheMatcher);
        }
        else{LineContainsIban = false;}
    }
    return FoundIbans;
}


/**
 * @Brief Method extracts Amounts out of the text with help of REGEXAmounts
 * 
 * @return List of strings with all the found amounts.
 */
public static List<String> ExtractAmounts(){
    //Initializing our variables
    List<String> FoundAmounts =  new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean LineContainsAmount = true;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEXAmounts);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(CopyOfText);
    while (LineContainsAmount) {
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String NumberFoundByTheMatcher = matcher.group(0);
            FoundAmounts.add(NumberFoundByTheMatcher);
        }
        else{LineContainsAmount = false;}
    }
    return FoundAmounts;
}


/**
 * @Brief Method extracts post codes out of the text with help of REGEXPostCode
 * 
 * @return List of strings with all the found post codes.
 */
public static List<String> ExtractPostCodes(){
    List<String> FoundPostCodes = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean LineContainsPostCode = true;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEXPostCode);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(CopyOfText);
    while(LineContainsPostCode) {
        if(matcher.find()) {
            String PostCodeFoundByMatcher = matcher.group(0);
            FoundPostCodes.add(PostCodeFoundByMatcher);
        }
        else {
            LineContainsPostCode = false;
        }
    }
    return FoundPostCodes;
}
```

}